# Which voltage is lower, 0V or -1V for connecting a MOSFET's source terminal?

Tags: voltage, mosfet, nmos, pmos, biasing

In an NMOS transistor the source should always be connected to the lowest voltage. Does this mean that if the source was originally grounded, but then the drain was connected to -1V that the source and drain would flip? This would lead to the source being connected to -1V and the drain connected to 0V. Please correct me if I am wrong, I am not sure my understanding is correct.

Thank you!

Comment: It says *should*, it doesn't say anything about flipping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A MOSFET in its purest form is a four-terminal device, and the body is not shorted to the source.

**In this case** we don't say that "the NMOS source is connected to the lowest voltage" we say "the terminal with the lowest voltage (of the source/drain pair) **is** the NMOS source".

So, leaving out the gate and body, which are physically different, which ever NMOS terminal is connected to the lower voltage is the source, and whichever terminal is connected to the higher voltage is the drain.

Comment: Thank you, that makes more sense. So in the case where I have -1V at one terminal and 0V at the other terminal (gate is connected to +1V), would the terminal with -1V become my source?

Comment: Yes, as long as the body is a separate connection. However, keep in mind that there is a PN junction between the body and the source so if the body voltage is 0.7V or so higher than the source you will forward bias the body/source junction and the device probably won't work very well. If the body is at -2V or -1V then you are fine.

Comment: So the body voltage should be connected to the source in this case since the source is also -1V?

Comment: No, the body does not need to be connected to the source. To prevent forward biasing of the body/source junction you would normally prevent the body voltage from being higher than the source voltage, but you can always make the body voltage more negative than the source voltage.

Comment: I see what you are saying, however in this case I cannot make the body voltage more negative than the source voltage. The only voltages I have available are +1V, 0V and -1V. Therefore, in order keep the body/source junction from becoming forward biased the body should also be connected to -1V which is the source voltage.

Answer (score 1):

In typical discreet NMOS transistors (3-terminal type) there is an intrinsic diode connection between the source and drain (because the body is shorted to the source) that is often not drawn in the symbol.

Here you can see it:

[image: https://instrumentationtools.com/power-mosfet/]

[image source](https://instrumentationtools.com/power-mosfet/)

If the drain goes more negative than the source by more than the forward voltage of that diode junction, it will conduct.  Possibly destroying the MOSFET.

If you are using a 4-terminal MOSFET where the body has its own connection, whichever of those two nodes is more negative will be the source.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question

Comment: Can you be more specific?  If the source is grounded and you apply -1 V to the drain, it doesn't suddenly make that the source, it will instead conduct through the body diode regardless of gate voltage.

Comment: @PrematureCorn Are you wondering if it is like a JFET where the source and drain can sometimes be interchangeable, depending on source and drain voltages?

Comment: No, the intrinsic diode is not a part of a MOSFET **in general**. MOSFETs are four-terminal devices.

Comment: Technically yes, but discreet NMOS devices are almost always packaged as 3 terminal devices where this body diode is "built in" (body shorted to source)

Comment: But not all NMOS devices are packaged as discrete transistors so the first sentence of your answer is, in general, false. And it is not necessarily "part of the structure of the MOSFET itself".

Comment: You do make a good point, I will edit to be more clear, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Considering an n channel mosfet.

Let's say the mosfet has 4 terminals - terminal 1, terminal 2, body and gate.

There are 2 diodes inevitably formed in the construction of the mosfet, one diode from the body to terminal 1 and a second diode from the body to terminal 2. The two diodes have their anodes connected to the body.

In the vast majority of available mosfets the body is pre-connected to either terminal 1 or terminal 2 which shorts out one of the diodes. Whichever of the two terminals the body is connected to becomes the source leaving the second diode connected between the source (and body) and the other terminal which has become the drain. The cathode of this second diode is therefore connected to the drain with its anode connected to the source.

This means that the drain must not be taken more than about 0.7V negative with respect to the source or the diode will conduct heavily.

So there is an asymmetry in mosfets.

Of course if you keep the drain-source voltage less than a few hundred mV (below the voltage where the drain-source diode starts to turn on) then the mosfet can be treated as symmetrical and then the terminal which is at the more negative voltage (out of terminal 1 and terminal 2) becomes the source.

When a mosfet is used, in a circuit design, as a variable resistor it is recommended to keep the drain source voltage below about plus & minus 200mV.